# two computers on same branch don't get synced

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a "dev" branch at work. I was working on the same branch at home, and when I committed some changes at home, my workspace at work wasn't updated. It still shows I'm on previous commit.
I'm using Eclipse. 
How can I fetch at work the commit that was made at home without ruining anything?

Comment: Do you expect the changes from one machine ("work") to automatically be delivered to another machine ("home") without any user interaction?

Comment: well I suppose I just thought they both track the same remote branch.. therefore any update should be visible on both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did a `git push` at home, simply do a `git pull` at work and you will see the changes. If you have not done a `git push` from home, you will have to do that first.

Comment: How do I do this in eclipse git view? it seems I can only do pull for the repository , not the branch . Or is that the same?
Thank you

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the eclipse UI; what happens when you pull the repository? Is your local branch associated with a remote tracking branch?

Comment: well I think it is , I have this branch in Local "dev" as well as in Remote Tracking : "origin/dev"
and they both show the same commit(it's stated near the branch's name).
if I press right-click on "origin/dev" I don't have any fetch/pull option.
Only if I press on the repository I have "Fetch from upstream", "Pull", and "Remote"-> "fetch". 
Is it ok if I pull the rep? will it not screw up my working branch ?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and pull the repository.

Comment: Are you sure pushed to the remote when you were at home?

Comment: Phew.. It's all good. I was afraid the pull would screw up my branch.. 
I guess I'm very cautious when it comes to git, after a few unfortunate incidents.. :)
Thanks!